# Why Python string type is also equal to bytes in assertions?

Tags: python-3.x, typing

I'm wondering after why these assertions are passing

```
    token_generated = ".eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJlbWFpbCI6ImRhdmlkLmJhcnJhdEBub3ZhcnRpcy5jb20iLCJleHBpcmF0aW9uIjoiMjAxOC0wMS0xMVQyMjowNTozMi44MjIwNDUifQ.jalHa2ZpnxH00v3tP6CKL3nUkiTMt4rsjo6P3DM32DA"


    self.assertTrue(type(token_generated) == str)
    self.assertTrue(type(token_generated) == bytes)
```

Both tests pass, but I don't understand why my token variable can have two types as it should be only a String

Because when I'm printing the type of `token_generated`

```
    print (type(token_generated))
```

I got that : `.<type 'str'>`

Comment: Are you sure you aren't using Python 2.x?  Under 2.7 at least, `bytes` is another name for the `str` type (something done in preparation for the 3.x change to have `str` be Unicode).

Comment: Oups yes, I was running my tests with python2.7, I switched to python3 and the first assertion is False

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using Python 2, the `str`- and `bytes`-type are actually the same

```
>>> bytes is str
True
```

Therefore they are also equal.

If you want to know if `token` is a valid utf8-string, you should decode it:

```
token = '\xff'
try:
    token.decode('utf8')
except UnicodeDecodeError:
    print "The bytes are just bytes, or maybe some other encoding"
else:
    print "The bytes are a utf8 string, hooray"
```